# swift build error on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, curl, swift3, libcurl, vapor

I am trying to install vapor (https://github.com/vapor/vapor) toolbox on a server which is running Ubuntu 15.10 x64.

I am getting this error from the "swift build" command

```
/swift-3.0/usr/bin/swift-build: error while loading shared libraries:    libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Is this a curl issue?  How can I resolve this error?**

## Details:

I am following the steps described here:
https://vapor.github.io/documentation/getting-started/install-toolbox.html

Swift 3.0 has been installed:

```
user@server:~$ swift --version
Swift version 3.0 (swift-3.0-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

To install the toolbox:

```
user@server:~$ curl -sL toolbox.vapor.sh | bash

✅  Compatible
Downloading...
Compiling...
/swift-3.0/usr/bin/swift-build: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Installing...
bash: line 22: .build/release/Executable: No such file or directory
Use vapor --help and vapor <command> --help to learn more.
```

The error above happens at this line in the script: `swift build -c release > /dev/null;`

`swift build --help` gives this same error:

```
user@server:~$ swift build --help
/swift-3.0/usr/bin/swift-build: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

vapor is not present:

```
user@server:~$ vapor --help
vapor: command not found
```

Also curl info:

```
user@server:~$ sudo -i curl --version
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.43.0 GnuTLS/3.3.15 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

curl was installed with `sudo apt-get install curl` and did not report any errors.

`user@server:/usr/lib$ find . | grep curl` reports about 15 matches but none are exactly libcurl.so.4.  The closes matches are:

```
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.3.0
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.3
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This issue was resolved by running:

`user@server:$ sudo apt-get install libcurl3`

Comment: Worked for me as well. Maybe you should mark it as the correct answer? :-)